# Will a student refusal visa 8 years ago affect my work permit application for Canada?

Tags: visas, uk, canada, permits, working-visas

I was a student in the UK but my last visa renewal was refused late December. Early March I returned back to my country. It's been 8 years now

This year I got a job offer from a Canadian employer and I'm in the process to apply for a work permit to go to Canada. Will the UK visa refusal affect my current application for Canada? Note that I have a new passport now.

Answer (score 1):

No. But you should declare it to avoid being accused of deception.

Comment: Just to add: Changing your passport does not affect this. You are still identifiably the same person.